# Laravel query - get all users who post offer on admin user article

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

So as I write at title I need to get all users who post offer to an admin user article...
So I write:

```
public function userbase()
{
    return Offer::select('users.*')
                ->where('users.admin', 9)
                ->join('articles','articles.id','=','offers.article_id')
                ->join('users','users.id','=','articles.user_id')
                ->where('articles.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->orderBy('offers.created_at', 'desc')
                ->groupBy('users.id')
                ->get(); 
}
```

but I get just [] (which is not true) ...

I also try:

```
public function userbase()
{
     $user_ids = Article::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->join('offers')->on('offers.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
                ->join('users')->on('offers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->select('users.id')
                ->distinct()
                ->get();

  $users = User::whereIn('id', $user_ids);
  return $users;
}
```

but I get:
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join()

3. attempt was:

   public function userbase() { $articles = Auth::user()->articles()->get(); foreach ($articles as $article) {

   ```
    $offers = Offer::where('article_id', $article['id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

   }
   ```

   foreach ($offers as $offer) {

   ```
    $users = User::where('id', $offer['user_id'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

   }

   return $users;
   ```

   } 
   but offcource dont work...

Now I really dont know what to do next... PLEASE HELP...

also my MODEL:
Article:

```
public function offers() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

Offer:

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function article() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
}
```

So how I can get users who post offer to other user(admin) article...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this function in the User model:

```
public function scopeBase($query){
    $sql = <<<SQL
id IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT users.id FROM articles
    INNER JOIN offers
        ON articles.id=offers.article_id
    INNER JOIN users 
        ON users.id=articles.user_id
    WHERE articles.user_id=? AND users.admin=?
)   
SQL;

    return $query->whereRaw($sql, [$this->id, 9]);
}
```

Then in the controller to get the users use this syntax:

```
class MyController extends Controller{
    public function example(){
        $users = User::base()->get();
        //....
    }

}
```

However if you explain better the table structure you will be grateful.

Comment: I get just: [] ... also there is syntax error return $query->whereRaw($sql, [$this->id, 9]);

Comment: Corrected the syntax

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
foreach (User::all() as $user) {
foreach ($user->offers as $offer) {
        if ($offer->article->user->isAdmin()) 
            $select[] = $user;
   }
}
```